# Do While Loop to get an Input

Tags: c++

In my c++ code I want to get an input from the user repeatedly until the user inputs "0" as the input. But the loop doesn't work at all.
Here is my code....

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int option;

do
{
    cout<<"Enter your Option"<<endl;
    cin>>option;


}
while(option == 0);
char ch;
cin>>ch;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The loop does work as coded: try entering zero, your loop will continue on and on.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "doesn't work at all" part? *How* doesn't it work? What happens when you run it? Perhaps you should learn how to debug your programs(https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? Or perhaps just learn basic logic?

Comment: Hint: `do/while` takes a continuation condition; you asked the loop to proceed for as long as the user enters zero.

Comment: I'm torn between flagging as an incomplete problem description or a simple typographic error.

Comment: `while(x)` is the opposite of `until(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assign an initial value to your `option` variable so that it isn't undefined by default, and change the do-while condition to `while (option != 0)`.

Your current code will only loop if `option` is equal to zero.

Comment: Being uninitialised is irrelevant and not a problem here. It's still allowed to write to it, and the check is only performed after that occurs.

Comment: @underscore_d agreed! Thanks